# Как убрать дубликаты в массиве с объединением значений?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив в котором каждый элемент тоже является массивом. 
Например,

```
["Текст1", 1, 0, 0, 0]
["Текст1", 0, 0, 2, 0]
["Текст2", 1, 0, 0, 0]
["Текст2", 0, 3, 0, 0]
["Текст3", 0, 0, 2, 0]
```

Как убрать дубликаты, но при этом объединить данные заменяя нули на другие значения у одинаковых значений "Текст" используя JS или JQuery? Чтобы получился массив:

```
    ["Текст1", 1, 0, 2, 0]
    ["Текст2", 1, 3, 0, 0]
    ["Текст3", 0, 0, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  ["Текст1", 1, 0, 0, 0],
  ["Текст1", 0, 0, 2, 0],
  ["Текст2", 1, 0, 0, 0],
  ["Текст2", 0, 3, 0, 0],
  ["Текст3", 0, 0, 2, 0]
];
let arr2 = [];

let obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!obj[item[0]]) {
    obj[item[0]] = item;
  } else {
    item.forEach(function(item2, index2) {
      if (obj[item[0]][index2] === 0) {
        obj[item[0]][index2] = item2;
      }
    });
  }
});

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
  arr2.push(obj[item]);
});

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Благодарю за оперативный ответ, это именно то что нужно. Несколько дней ломал голову, а оказалось что решение довольно простое.

Comment: рад помочь, так бывает, ломаешь голову, а ответ очень простой ))))