# Как удалить из массива повторяющиеся имена?

Tags: javascript

Например, есть массив объектов:

```js
var array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-08' },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-20'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01'},
]
```

На выходе - оставить только имя с последней датой добавления:

```js
var array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-08' },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-20'},
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01'},
]
```

Удалились `{name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'}`, `{name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-08'}`,         `{name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01'}`

В итоге остались уникальные имена и с последней датой добавления.

Comment: Задание понятно. Что Вы уже сделали?

Comment: [дубликаты вопроса про удаление дубликатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать дубликаты в массиве с объединением значений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836955/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю сортировка лишняя если как в желаемом ответе.

```js
var array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-08' },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-20'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01'},
]

let result = [...array]
    .reduce((a, c) => (a.map(e=>e.name).includes(c.name) || a.push(c), a), []);

console.log(result);
```

А если просить тотже ответ но с последней датой обновления

```js
var array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-08' },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-20'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01'},
]

let result = array.filter(item => [...array]
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))
    .reduce((a, c) => (a.map(e=>e.name).includes(c.name) || a.push(c), a), []).includes(item));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Сортируем по дате. Потом проходимся по каждому элементу и проверяем есть ли он в массиве уже.

```js
const arr = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-08' },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01'},
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01'},
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-20'},
];

console.log(
  arr
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))
    .reduce((a, c) => {
      if (Object.values(a).map(e=>e.name).indexOf(c.name) === -1) a.push(c);
      return a;
    }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если массив большой настолько, что стоит задумываться об оптимизации, можно сэкономить на сортировке и перепроверках с перебором массива, но нужно ещё проверить, будет ли какой-нибудь выигрыш:

```js
const array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-08' },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-20'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01'},
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02'},
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01'},
];

const result = Object.values(array.reduce(
  (acc, { name, date }) => {
    if (!acc[name] || acc[name].date < date) acc[name] = { name, date };
    return acc;
  },
  {},
));

console.log(result);
```